# PDF Custom Http Header in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

i'm trying to add a custom header to PDF & XML Files to hide them from search engines.

Google explained it for apache like this:

```
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

Any ideas how it's possible in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net mvc you can use ActionLink with proper overload

```
 @Html.ActionLink("PDF", "/pdf.pdf", null, new {title = "pdf file", rel="noindex, nofollow")
```

it 'll generate code like

```
 <a href="/pdf.pdf" rel="noindex, nofollow" title="pdf file">PDF</a>
```

Comment: I'm searching for a solution to add the http header to PDF files.